# sed: skip the first occurence of a match, then for all the other occurences, delete the whole line containing the match

Tags: sed, gnu

I want to achieve this:

- Skip the first occurence of a match
- For all the other occurences (except the first)
- Delete the entire line containing that occurence

So for example if I have this text:

```
<div>
    <p>First text</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Second text</p>
    <p>Third text</p>
</div>
```

And I am matching for `<p>`

I want the output to be:

```
<div>
    <p>First text</p>
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

I tried `sed '0,/<p>/! /<p>/d'`, but it outputs `` unknown command: `/' `` .

How could I achieve my desired result?
I am yet a novice, so my mistake could come off as silly.
Would appreciate a lot if you could help.

Comment: A common guidance is to not use regex-based tools to manipulate structured formats. For XML, use an XML-specific tool like an XPath processor.

Answer (score 1):

From the question, it looks to me that you are not considering cases where `<p>` and `</p>` are on different lines, nor that you even care about `</p>`; you're just deleting all lines containing `<p>`, except for the first such line.

The following command should do the job:

```sh
sed -z 's/<p>/\x0/;s/[^\n]*<p>[^\n]*\n//g;s/\x0/<p>/' input_file
```

This solution has a fairly simple logic:

- it marks and "hides" the first `<p>`;
- deletes all the lines containing `<p>`, except the first one where `<p>` is "hidden";
- restores the "hidden" `<p>`.

Detailed explanation:

- the option `-z` makes Sed treat the file as a single string consisting of all lines concateneted, with each line terminating by `\n`;
- the Sed command consists of 3 parts separated by `;`:

  1. `s/<p>/\x0/` changes the first `<p>` to `\x0` which is not a character present in the file;
  2. `s/[^\n]*<p>[^\n]*\n//g` deletes (actually substitutes with the empty string) any line which contains only non-`\n`s with a n`<p>` somewhere, all followed by `\n`; the first line containing `<p>` is not deleted because it doesn't contain `<p>` since after step 1;
  3. `s/\x0/<p>/` changes the marker `\x0` back to `<p>`.

Comment: When `<p>First text</p><p>second text</p>` are on one line, both are deleted.

Comment: _For all the other occurences (except the first) Delete the entire line containing that occurence_. So yes, technically the whole line must be deleted, even if that means deleting also the first occurrence. No?

Comment: I agree. I hope heeing this answer OP will consider `awk` too, but given the requirements your answer is fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to keep the second `<p>` when it is on the same line as the first, you can use

```
sed -rz ':a;s/(<p>.*\n)[^\n]*<p>[^\n]*\n/\1/;ta' file
```

When you really like `sed`, you can use

```
sed -n '1,/<p>/p' file; sed '/<p>/d' <(sed '1,/<p>/d' file)
```

You wanted `sed`, I will show an `awk` solution too:

```
awk '/<p>/ && delp {next}
     /<p>/ {delp=1}
     1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you  (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<p>/{x;/./{x;d};x;h}' file
```

If the current line does not contain `<p>`, print as normal.

If the current line contains `<p>` and there is a copy in the hold space, delete the current line.

Otherwise copy the current line to the hold space and print as normal.

---

Alternative:

```
sed -z 's/.*<p>.*\n//2mg' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution which uses a fairly more complex logic, but consists of a shorter command:

```sh
sed 'x;s/<p>/&/;x;ta;bb;:a;/<p>/d;:b;H' input_file
```

Here's a pseudo-code describing the logic:

```
if one of previous lines contains <p>
    set flag to true
else
    set/leave flag to false
end
if flag
    if line contains <p>
        delete line
    end
end
```

Detailed explanation:

- unlike [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68336992/5825294), it ***doesn't*** use the `-z` option, which means that the script is run for every line of the input file
- the script does the following (again the commands are separated by `;`s):

  1. `x` swaps (e`x`changes) the content of the pattern space (whose content is "normally" the line that's being processed) with that of the hold space (a register where you can store stuff which initially empty; see step 7 to see how we use it in this script);
  2. `s/<p>/&/` searches for `<p>` in the current content of the pattern space, which means the content of the hold space before step 1 was run, and replaces it with itself (`&`); this is a no-op as regards the text being processed, but it sets to *true* an internal flag that means that the last executed `s` command was successful; in fact this `s` command acts like *if the pattern space contains `<p>` set the flag to true, otherwise leave it to false*;
  3. `x` swaps pattern and hold space again; the net effect of these first steps (1, 2, and 3) is that the text has not been changed, and the internal flag is set to *true* if ***the hold space contains a `<p>`***;
  4. `ta` test the flag and, if it is true, the control is moved to where `:a` is; this means that if the hold space contains `<p>`, we continue with step 5, othewise we jump to step 6
  5. (this is right after `:a`) `/<p>/d` deletes the current line being processed if it contains `<p>`;
  6. (we are here if the test at step 4 had negative result, i.e. the hold space doesn't contain `<p>`) `bb` unconditionally `b`ranches (jumps) to where `:b` is, which means that we have simply skipped step 5, i.e. we have let a line containing `<p>` go, without deleting it;
  7. `H` appends the current pattern space to the hold space; in practice, we are accumulating line after line to the hold space as we read them.

Answer (score 0):

You were close with `0,/<p>/! /<p>/d`! The `/pat/` or `/pat/!` can't be followed by `//` immiedately - you need `{ }`, thus a syntax error.

No need to repeat the `<p>` pattern - empty pattern reuses the last one.

```
$ printf "%s\n" a '<p>' c d '<p>' '<p>' '<p>' e | sed '0,/<p>/!{//d}'
a
<p>
c
d
e
```